# How to send file descriptor to child process using msgsend?

Tags: c, unix

I can’t understand how to use msgsend and msgrecv to send file descriptors to the child process. How do I fill in struct msghdr and struct cmsghdr for this to work?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?

Comment: What are `msgsend` and `msgrecv`? Do you mean `sendmsg` and `recvmsg` instead?